# Not able to create graph links/edges using networkx and d3

Tags: python, rest, api, d3.js, networkx

I'm trying to create simple graph of nodes and edges from rest api call... So far able to get nodes, dump it as a json and send to d3 for visualization.
The problem here I'm not able to graph edges or links. It give me an error below

```
e = (link['link']['destination']['node']['node-id'], link['link']['source']['node']['node-id'])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is details of nodes and links call from ODL REST API

```
Nodes List:
Node ID -  openflow:1
Node ID -  host:00:00:00:00:00:01
Node ID -  openflow:2
Node ID -  host:00:00:00:00:00:02

Links List:
Link ID -  host:00:00:00:00:00:01/openflow:1:1
Link ID -  openflow:2:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:02
Link ID -  openflow:1:2
Link ID -  openflow:2:2
Link ID -  openflow:1:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:01
Link ID -  host:00:00:00:00:00:02/openflow:2:1
```

This is details info call from the API

```
{
  u'network-topology': {
    u'topology': [
      {
        u'node': [
          {
            u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']",
            u'node-id': u'openflow:1',
            u'termination-point': [
              {
                u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:2']",
                u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:2'
              },
              {
                u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:1']",
                u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:1'
              },
              {
                u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:LOCAL']",
                u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:LOCAL'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            u'host-tracker-service:addresses': [
              {
                u'first-seen': 1562655393902,
                u'ip': u'10.0.0.1',
                u'mac': u'00:00:00:00:00:01',
                u'id': 6,
                u'last-seen': 1562655393902
              }
            ],
            u'host-tracker-service:id': u'00:00:00:00:00:01',
            u'host-tracker-service:attachment-points': [
              {
                u'active': True,
                u'corresponding-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01',
                u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:1'
              }
            ],
            u'node-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01',
            u'termination-point': [
              {
                u'tp-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']",
            u'node-id': u'openflow:2',
            u'termination-point': [
              {
                u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:LOCAL']",
                u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:LOCAL'
              },
              {
                u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:1']",
                u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:1'
              },
              {
                u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:2']",
                u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:2'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            u'host-tracker-service:addresses': [
              {
                u'first-seen': 1562655393906,
                u'ip': u'10.0.0.2',
                u'mac': u'00:00:00:00:00:02',
                u'id': 7,
                u'last-seen': 1562655393906
              }
            ],
            u'host-tracker-service:id': u'00:00:00:00:00:02',
            u'host-tracker-service:attachment-points': [
              {
                u'active': True,
                u'corresponding-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02',
                u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:1'
              }
            ],
            u'node-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02',
            u'termination-point': [
              {
                u'tp-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02'
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        u'link': [
          {
            u'link-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01/openflow:1:1',
            u'destination': {
              u'dest-node': u'openflow:1',
              u'dest-tp': u'openflow:1:1'
            },
            u'source': {
              u'source-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01',
              u'source-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01'
            }
          },
          {
            u'link-id': u'openflow:2:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:02',
            u'destination': {
              u'dest-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02',
              u'dest-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02'
            },
            u'source': {
              u'source-tp': u'openflow:2:1',
              u'source-node': u'openflow:2'
            }
          },
          {
            u'link-id': u'openflow:1:2',
            u'destination': {
              u'dest-node': u'openflow:2',
              u'dest-tp': u'openflow:2:2'
            },
            u'source': {
              u'source-tp': u'openflow:1:2',
              u'source-node': u'openflow:1'
            }
          },
          {
            u'link-id': u'openflow:2:2',
            u'destination': {
              u'dest-node': u'openflow:1',
              u'dest-tp': u'openflow:1:2'
            },
            u'source': {
              u'source-tp': u'openflow:2:2',
              u'source-node': u'openflow:2'
            }
          },
          {
            u'link-id': u'openflow:1:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:01',
            u'destination': {
              u'dest-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01',
              u'dest-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01'
            },
            u'source': {
              u'source-tp': u'openflow:1:1',
              u'source-node': u'openflow:1'
            }
          },
          {
            u'link-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02/openflow:2:1',
            u'destination': {
              u'dest-node': u'openflow:2',
              u'dest-tp': u'openflow:2:1'
            },
            u'source': {
              u'source-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02',
              u'source-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02'
            }
          }
        ],
        u'topology-id': u'flow:1'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the code i test with, where It can only get the nodes but not the links/edges...

```
# get nodes
resp, content = h.request(url, "GET")
nodeData = json.loads(content)
topology = nodeData['network-topology']['topology'][0]
print "Nodes List:"
for i in range(len(topology['node'])):
    print "Node ID - ", topology['node'][i]['node-id']
    i += 1

# Get links/edges
resp, content = h.request(url, "GET")
linkData = json.loads(content)
topology = linkData['network-topology']['topology'][0]
print "Links List:"
for i in range(len(topology['link'])):
    print "Link ID - ", topology['link'][i]['link-id']
    i += 1


# Add nodes and links into graph
graph = nx.Graph()
for node in range(len(topology['node'])):
    graph.add_node(topology['node'][node]['node-id'])
for link in range(len(topology['link'])):
    e = (link['link']['destination']['node']['node-id'], link['link']['source']['node']['node-id'])
    graph.add_edge(*e)


print "Graph Nodes:"
print graph.nodes()
print "Graph Links:"
print graph.links()

# write json formatted data to use in visualization
d = json_graph.node_link_data(graph)
json.dump(d, open('topo.json','w'))
print('Wrote node-link JSON data')
```

I tried by removing codes related with link/edge and remain node and no problem..I can get the details of nodes in topo.json..but when i add graph for links I got problem

The problem here I'm not able to graph edges or links. It give me an error below

```
e = (link['link']['destination']['node']['node-id'], link['link']['source']['node']['node-id'])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I just don't know how to resolve it...appreciate advises and help from experts here..Thanks

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

I modified below but getting different error TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
# Get links/edges
resp, content = h.request(url, "GET")
linkData = json.loads(content)
a = linkData['network-topology']['topology'][0]
print a

# Add links into graph
graph = nx.Graph()
for link in a:
    e = (link['link']['destination']['node']['node-id'], link['link']['source']['node']['node-id'])
    graph.add_edge(*e)
```

print a above give output below

```
{
  u'node': [
    {
      u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']",
      u'node-id': u'openflow:1',
      u'termination-point': [
        {
          u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:2']",
          u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:2'
        },
        {
          u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:1']",
          u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:1'
        },
        {
          u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:LOCAL']",
          u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:LOCAL'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      u'host-tracker-service:addresses': [
        {
          u'first-seen': 1562655393902,
          u'ip': u'10.0.0.1',
          u'mac': u'00:00:00:00:00:01',
          u'id': 6,
          u'last-seen': 1562655393902
        }
      ],
      u'host-tracker-service:id': u'00:00:00:00:00:01',
      u'host-tracker-service:attachment-points': [
        {
          u'active': True,
          u'corresponding-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01',
          u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:1'
        }
      ],
      u'node-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01',
      u'termination-point': [
        {
          u'tp-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']",
      u'node-id': u'openflow:2',
      u'termination-point': [
        {
          u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:LOCAL']",
          u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:LOCAL'
        },
        {
          u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:1']",
          u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:1'
        },
        {
          u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:2']",
          u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:2'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      u'host-tracker-service:addresses': [
        {
          u'first-seen': 1562655393906,
          u'ip': u'10.0.0.2',
          u'mac': u'00:00:00:00:00:02',
          u'id': 7,
          u'last-seen': 1562655393906
        }
      ],
      u'host-tracker-service:id': u'00:00:00:00:00:02',
      u'host-tracker-service:attachment-points': [
        {
          u'active': True,
          u'corresponding-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02',
          u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:1'
        }
      ],
      u'node-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02',
      u'termination-point': [
        {
          u'tp-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  u'link': [
    {
      u'link-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01/openflow:1:1',
      u'destination': {
        u'dest-node': u'openflow:1',
        u'dest-tp': u'openflow:1:1'
      },
      u'source': {
        u'source-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01',
        u'source-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01'
      }
    },
    {
      u'link-id': u'openflow:2:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:02',
      u'destination': {
        u'dest-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02',
        u'dest-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02'
      },
      u'source': {
        u'source-tp': u'openflow:2:1',
        u'source-node': u'openflow:2'
      }
    },
    {
      u'link-id': u'openflow:1:2',
      u'destination': {
        u'dest-node': u'openflow:2',
        u'dest-tp': u'openflow:2:2'
      },
      u'source': {
        u'source-tp': u'openflow:1:2',
        u'source-node': u'openflow:1'
      }
    },
    {
      u'link-id': u'openflow:2:2',
      u'destination': {
        u'dest-node': u'openflow:1',
        u'dest-tp': u'openflow:1:2'
      },
      u'source': {
        u'source-tp': u'openflow:2:2',
        u'source-node': u'openflow:2'
      }
    },
    {
      u'link-id': u'openflow:1:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:01',
      u'destination': {
        u'dest-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01',
        u'dest-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01'
      },
      u'source': {
        u'source-tp': u'openflow:1:1',
        u'source-node': u'openflow:1'
      }
    },
    {
      u'link-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02/openflow:2:1',
      u'destination': {
        u'dest-node': u'openflow:2',
        u'dest-tp': u'openflow:2:1'
      },
      u'source': {
        u'source-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02',
        u'source-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02'
      }
    }
  ],
  u'topology-id': u'flow:1'
}
```

Still trying to resolve it...no luck so far...

**Need to get all the nodes and links(source and destination) from API call and save it onto json file and send to d3.js for graph visulaization. Please advise. Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

This for loop:

```
for link in range(len(topology['link'])):
    e = (link['link']['destination']['node']['node-id'], link['link']['source']['node']['node-id'])
    graph.add_edge(*e)
```

tells Python to assign `link` the values `0`, `1`, `2`, ... up to the length of `topology['link']` (well, the length minus 1).  This explains the error in the first line of the for loop the first time it goes through when it tries to find the entry `['link']` in the integer `0`.  Integers don't have such entries.

Do you mean to do `for link in topology['link']:` or something else?  It appears you expect `link` to be a dict of some form.

---

There are other concerns with your code.

```
for i in range(len(topology['link'])):
    print "Link ID - ", topology['link'][i]['link-id']
    i += 1
```

The `i+=1` does not make much sense at the end of the block because the next time it loops through, `i` is given a new value from the for loop.  I also wonder if there is a hidden error in your for loop over `topology['node']`, similar to the one in the loop that's giving the error.

Comment: Hi Joel...I have exclude link from the program and remain node related code and it does work and able send the node list onto topo.json and able to see the nodes via d3 (of course without the links).... I no the problem somewhere in for loop link...but now I stuck here...  The source from where i got the nodes and links is from the topology detail that I call via rest api...I have share the details on my post above... thanks for your responses

Comment: ``` for i in range(len(topology['link'])):
    print "Link ID - ", topology['link'][i]['link-id']
    i += 1 ``` this give list of link as below ``` Links List:
Link ID -  host:00:00:00:00:00:01/openflow:1:1
Link ID -  openflow:2:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:02
Link ID -  openflow:1:2
Link ID -  openflow:2:2
Link ID -  openflow:1:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:01
Link ID -  host:00:00:00:00:00:02/openflow:2:1 ``` I think the problem is when I want to add links onto networkx graph....